# Output matrix with common elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Given lists of lists like a and b, I want to obtain an output like c.

```
a = {{2, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}}; b = {{2, 2, 0}, { 2, 2, 1}};  

c = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 1}}
```

If the same position has a different value or zero, it should output zero. What's the elegant, non-loopy way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
MapThread[#1 Boole[#1 == #2] &, {a, b}, 2]
```

Answer (score 8):

This will be *vastly* faster for large lists:

```
BitXor[1, Unitize[Subtract[a, b]]]*a
```